# Grouping connected linestrings in PostGIS?

Tags: postgis, linestring, streets, connectivity-analysis

I have a table of streets I've selected based on a set of attributes (let's say it's `speed_limit < 25`).  There are groups of streets that are locally contiguous;  I'd like to group these sets of connected linestrings into GeometryCollections.  In the image below, there would be two GeometryCollections: one with the red lines and one with the blue lines.

[image]

I tried running a couple of "dissolve, deaggregate" queries along the lines of:

```
SELECT (ST_Dump(st_union)).geom
FROM 
    (SELECT ST_Union(geom) FROM roads) sq
```

With everything I've tried, I either end up with a single feature (`ST_Union`) or my original geometry (`ST_Dump` of `ST_Union`).

Maybe it's possible to do this with some kind of `WITH RECURSIVE` magic?

Comment: Something doesn't look right with "(ST_Dump(st_union)).geom"

Comment: Since he didn't alias ST_Union(geom) the name of the new geom inherited the name of the function to become st_union.  That's why it looks a little funny

Answer (score 20, accepted):

So, by example. Here's a simple table with two connected groups of edges:

```
drop table lines;
create table lines ( id integer primary key, geom geometry(linestring) );
insert into lines (id, geom) values ( 1, 'LINESTRING(0 0, 0 1)');
insert into lines (id, geom) values ( 2, 'LINESTRING(0 1, 1 1)');
insert into lines (id, geom) values ( 3, 'LINESTRING(1 1, 1 2)');
insert into lines (id, geom) values ( 4, 'LINESTRING(1 2, 2 2)');
insert into lines (id, geom) values ( 11, 'LINESTRING(10 10, 10 11)');
insert into lines (id, geom) values ( 12, 'LINESTRING(10 11, 11 11)');
insert into lines (id, geom) values ( 13, 'LINESTRING(11 11, 11 12)');
insert into lines (id, geom) values ( 14, 'LINESTRING(11 12, 12 12)');
create index lines_gix on lines using gist(geom);
```

Now, here's a recursive function that, given the id of an edge, accumulates all the edges that touch:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION find_connected(integer) returns integer[] AS
$$
WITH RECURSIVE lines_r AS (
  SELECT ARRAY[id] AS idlist, geom, id
  FROM lines 
  WHERE id = $1
  UNION ALL
  SELECT array_append(lines_r.idlist, lines.id) AS idlist, 
         lines.geom AS geom, 
         lines.id AS id
  FROM lines, lines_r
  WHERE ST_Touches(lines.geom, lines_r.geom)
  AND NOT lines_r.idlist @> ARRAY[lines.id]
)
SELECT 
  array_agg(id) AS idlist
  FROM lines_r
$$ 
LANGUAGE 'sql';
```

That just leaves us needing to find, after each group is accumulated, the id of an edge that is not already part of a group. Which, tragically, requires a second recursive query.

```
WITH RECURSIVE groups_r AS (
  (SELECT find_connected(id) AS idlist, 
          find_connected(id) AS grouplist, 
          id FROM lines WHERE id = 1)
  UNION ALL
  (SELECT array_cat(groups_r.idlist,find_connected(lines.id)) AS idlist,
         find_connected(lines.id) AS grouplist,
         lines.id
  FROM lines, groups_r
  WHERE NOT idlist @> ARRAY[lines.id]
  LIMIT 1)
)
SELECT id, grouplist
FROM groups_r;
```

Which taken together return a nice set with the seed id and each group it accumulated. I leave it as an exercise to the reader to turn the arrays of id back into a query to create geometry for mapping.

```
 id |   grouplist   
----+---------------
  1 | {1,2,3,4}
 11 | {11,12,13,14}
(2 rows)
```

Comment: I think this code could be simpler, if the geometry type supporting hashing in PostgreSQL (when you write a simpler RCTE that doesn't involve accumulating arrays of ids, you get an error "All column datatypes must be hashable"), so there's a little enhancement request for me.

Comment: This is a really awesome approach.  I'm noticing some odd results as I apply it to a larger test set; I'll see if I can reduce the issue to a simple example.

100 lines: 85 clusters,  largest cluster=3,   0.03 s //// 
200 lines: 144 clusters, largest cluster=9,    0.08 s ////  
300 lines: 180 clusters, largest cluster=51,   0.16 s //// 
400 lines: 188 clusters, largest cluster=41,   0.27 s ////  
500 lines: 176 clusters, largest cluster=112,  0.56 s //// 
600 lines: 143 clusters, largest cluster=449,  1.0 s  //// 
650 lines: 133 clusters, largest cluster=7601, 6.8 s

Comment: Adding this to the test data will cause duplicate IDs in the `grouplist` array:  `insert into lines (id, geom) values ( 15, 'LINESTRING(0 0, 10 10)');`.  Changing `array_agg(id)` in the function return to `array_agg(DISTINCT id)` seems to resolve the issue.

Comment: This is a good solution, so now how can we store the geometries in a table so that we can see the connected lines?

Answer (score 7):

Here's an approach that uses a temporary table to incrementally aggregate clusters together.  I don't really care for the temporary table approach, but this seems to perform quite well as the number of lines increases (I have 1.2 M lines in my input).

```
DO
$$
DECLARE
this_id bigint;
this_geom geometry;
cluster_id_match integer;

id_a bigint;
id_b bigint;

BEGIN
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS clusters;
CREATE TABLE clusters (cluster_id serial, ids bigint[], geom geometry);
CREATE INDEX ON clusters USING GIST(geom);

-- Iterate through linestrings, assigning each to a cluster (if there is an intersection)
-- or creating a new cluster (if there is not)
FOR this_id, this_geom IN SELECT id, geom FROM lines LOOP
  -- Look for an intersecting cluster.  (There may be more than one.)
  SELECT cluster_id FROM clusters WHERE ST_Intersects(this_geom, clusters.geom)
     LIMIT 1 INTO cluster_id_match;

  IF cluster_id_match IS NULL THEN
     -- Create a new cluster
     INSERT INTO clusters (ids, geom) VALUES (ARRAY[this_id], this_geom);
  ELSE
     -- Append line to existing cluster
     UPDATE clusters SET geom = ST_Union(this_geom, geom),
                          ids = array_prepend(this_id, ids)
      WHERE clusters.cluster_id = cluster_id_match;
  END IF;
END LOOP;

-- Iterate through the clusters, combining clusters that intersect each other
LOOP
    SELECT a.cluster_id, b.cluster_id FROM clusters a, clusters b 
     WHERE ST_Intersects(a.geom, b.geom)
       AND a.cluster_id < b.cluster_id
      INTO id_a, id_b;

    EXIT WHEN id_a IS NULL;
    -- Merge cluster A into cluster B
    UPDATE clusters a SET geom = ST_Union(a.geom, b.geom), ids = array_cat(a.ids, b.ids)
      FROM clusters b
     WHERE a.cluster_id = id_a AND b.cluster_id = id_b;

    -- Remove cluster B
    DELETE FROM clusters WHERE cluster_id = id_b;
END LOOP;
END;
$$ language plpgsql;
```

Comment: works perfectly

Comment: @zakariamouqcit Glad this worked for you! I wrote this answer before I wrote the `ST_ClusterIntersecting` function in PostGIS. If your data is small enough to fit into memory, I'd suggest checking that out for a more performant solution.

Comment: searching for this question brought me here. Tried the iterative and the st_clusterintersecting but found st_clusterDBScan to be the most apt. In case anyone else is brought here too. https://postgis.net/docs/manual-dev/ST_ClusterDBSCAN.html

Comment: Agreed, ST_ClusterDBSCAN is almost always the best way to go for PostGIS 2.3+