# PostGIS: how to merge contiguous features sharing same attributes values?

Tags: postgis, postgis-2.0, merge

I have a big PostGIS table storing line features.

I would like to merge features that are both connected to each other and have given attribute values identical. Here is below an example of what I'd like to achieve.

- The outmost features (black and blue ones) are not merged because there are not contiguous even if their attribute values are the same
- Features green and red are merged because they match both conditions
- Feature yellow is left as before.

How would you achieve that with a SQL query?
[image]

Answer (score 7):

You can do this with [ST_ClusterIntersecting](http://postgis.net/docs/manual-2.2/ST_ClusterIntersecting.html):

```
SELECT attr, unnest(ST_ClusterIntersecting(geom))
FROM lines
GROUP by attr;
```

Comment: Thanks @dbaston! I'll try it in the coming days and let you know.

Comment: The function `ST_ClusterIntersecting()` is available from PostGIS 2.2... Is there a solution with an older version? I'm on PostGIS 2.1.8 and I can't upgrade PostGIS for the moment.

Comment: Nothing that I'd consider good....it's actually this situation that motivated me to write `ST_ClusterIntersecting`.  Some pre-2.2 ideas are at http://gis.stackexchange.com/q/94203/18189